# Spyder returning TypeError after updating to Spyder 4.1.4

Tags: spyder

This command failed to be executed because an error occurred while trying to get the file code from Spyder's editor. The error was:

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

TypeError: handle_get_file_code() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save_all'
```

Comment: I couldn't find a fix on google that's why I'm asking here

Comment: Strangely I have had the same error since yesterday without upgrading to 4.1.4 (I am still on 4.1.3...). Maybe it could be linked to `spyder-kernels`, since the error came when I started working with a new `venv`.

Comment: See also the developers' issue at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13715

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same issue on Spyder 4.1.4. I completely uninstalled spyder and reinstalled it to the latest version (which is 4.1.5 right now) and apparently they have resolved the underlying issue in this version. So, the following standard procedure should solve the problem, hopefully:

```
pip uninstall spyder
conda uninstall spyder
conda install spyder
```

I use the spyder in a conda env, hence I don't think `pip uninstall` is really necessary.

Comment: This worked for me (without the pip uninstall).  But there was was a complaint about "inconsistent environments", the culprit being  defaults/win-64::python-language-server==0.31.10=py37_0.  I chose to ignore that and Spyder 4.1.5 was duly installed and working.

Comment: Worked for me without pip uninstall. From spyder-4.1.3-py37_0 + spyder-kernels-1.9.4-py37_0 to spyder-4.1.5-py37_0 + spyder-kernels-1.9.4-py37_0. See also the developers' issue at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13715

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to come from the new version of the sub-package `spyder-kernels`

I've uninstalled the version 1.9.4

```
conda uninstall spyder-kernels
```

And came back to the previous version

```
conda install spyder-kernels=1.9.3
```

Comment: yes, I had the error when I started working with a new `venv`, so it could definitely be `spyder-kernels`

Comment: However I get the following after downgrading: 
`Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 1.9.4 and < 1.10.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.`

Comment: @Vincent did you find a solution yet, and if so, could you please share details?

Comment: @brethvoice sorry I had found the precise issue but cant seem to remember. Definitely something to do with spyder and spyder-kernels ; uninstalling / reinstalling will get you through

Comment: @Vincent it seems possible that different operating systems require different solutions.  Are you using POSIX, Mac, Windows...?

Comment: @brethvoice I am using Windows

Comment: @Vincent I just posted an answer below.  You might have to start over (which is what I did) with a fresh `conda` environment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64472103/12763497

Answer (score 4):

I updated to Spyder 4.1.4 this morning and ended up with the same issue when I tried to run my code. Worth noting I use Anaconda so not sure how that may impact you.

I tried reverting back to an older version of Spyder as well as upgrading to Spyder 4.1.5 via the Anaconda Prompt but was only successful in avoiding the error message you mention above by going into the Anaconda Navigator and removing the Spyder application entirely. I then installed Spyder 4.1.5 from the Anaconda Navigator and was able to run my code.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. Instead on uninstalling and reintsalling, open the anaconda prompt and run

`conda install spyder=4.1.5`

Close and reopen the spyder application. Your algorithm will work seemlessly.

Answer (score 3):

Updating to Spyder version 4.1.5 solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following upgrade solved the problem for me:

```
conda install spyder=4.1.5
```

I found the solution at the bottom of [this thread](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13715).

Comment: @user3385948 which operating system are you using (or does that not matter)?

Comment: I'm using Anaconda, installed on Windows 10 Pro x64 (latest version)

Answer (score 2):

It's bugs of Spyder 4.14, Upgrading to V4.15 ,Then getrid of your problem

Answer (score 1):

I had to combine some answers here.

First I removed spyder with:

```
pip uninstall spyder
conda uninstall spyder
```

After that I installed it again:

```
conda install spyder
```

This first part was based on @CrossEntropy answer.

This change did not solve the issue, but allowed me to **update spyder** to its newest version (4.1.5) as @quangtrank9 recommended.

This process avoid me to remove and reinstall anaconda. It would be an undesireble process.

Comment: Worked for me without pip uninstall. From spyder-4.1.3-py37_0 + spyder-kernels-1.9.4-py37_0 to spyder-4.1.5-py37_0 + spyder-kernels-1.9.4-py37_0. See also the developers' issue at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13715

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work, that's why I had to uninstall and after that install again.

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting any uninstall, I tried

```
> conda install spyder=4.1.5
```

These were the associated changes

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  jedi                                        0.14.1-py37_0 --> 0.17.1-py37_0
  python-language-s~ pkgs/main/win-64::python-language-ser~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::python-language-server-0.35.1-py_0
  spyder                                       4.0.0-py37_0 --> 4.1.5-py37_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  autopep8                               1.5.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> 1.5.6-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  flake8                                 3.9.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> 3.9.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  parso                                  0.8.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> 0.7.0-py_0
  pycodestyle                            2.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> 2.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyflakes                               2.3.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> 2.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  spyder-kernels                      1.10.2-py37haa95532_0 --> 1.9.4-py37_0
```

Note especially the downgrade of `spyder-kernels` to `1.9.4`.
That is likely the reason why

```
> conda install spyder-kernels=1.9.4
```

also [seems to work](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13715).

Note:
It is still somewhat puzzling to me that an update of a package leads to a downgrade of another.
Not that I don't understand from the programming/technical point of view how that can happen, but I wouldn't expect it to happen (and as often as it does).

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a combination of the answers that are provided here:

- First uninstall `spyder-kernels` using pip: `sudo pip3 uninstall spyder_kernels==1.9.4`
- Uninstall `spyder` using conda: `conda uninstall spyder`
- Install `spyder` using conda: `conda install spyder`

Answer (score 0):

conda update --all worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Following what is discussed here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13715, I just ran the command:

```
conda install spyder-kernels=1.9.3
```

and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  When following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64558857/12763497) answer's advice, I first did `conda update conda` followed by `conda update --all` as advised in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63894399/12763497) answer.  The following is a partial list of what `conda env export` returns on my Windows 10 conda (Python 3.7) environment which currently does *not* have this issue:

```
- spyder=4.1.5=py37_0
- spyder-kernels=1.9.4=py37_0
```